# Pass collection via ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, collections, viewbag

I have a website in ASP.NET MVC3. I want to pass collection to another view. I have this collection in `ViewBag`. Here is my `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show Report", "Report", new { workList = ViewBag.workReportList })
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Report(List<Work> workList)
{
    return View(workList);
}
```

But it is not working - it looks like the passed object is empty. 
When I am using the same object to `RenderPartial` everything is working fine.

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("WorkListTable", (IEnumerable<WorkWeb.Entities.Work>)ViewBag.workReportList);}
```

How can I pass this object to a View? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this (passing the controller name)?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show Report", "Report", "ControllerName", new { workList = ViewBag.workReportList }, null)
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried passing controller name. But it is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, it's to do with routing. change `workList` to `id` in both your ActionLink and in your ActionResult or add a new route where you accept `workList` as a parameter, something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ReportRoute", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{workList}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "Report", workList = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Replacing `ControllerName` with the name of your controller

Comment: Oh, my bad, I remember you can't post a collection via a link like that, you could do something suggested here perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682944/how-to-pass-ienumerable-model-in-parameter-of-html-actionlink